# JavaScript/jQuery signature pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, signaturepad

Would like to ask if there's a way for transferring `<canvas>` contents to another `<div>`. So that after putting the signature, it will be previewed on the inside of the `<div>` it was transferred to.

I've used this library https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad on our previous project and the signature looks real, like it was written by a pen.

This library can save the signature to a file, so what I did on our previous project is once I submit the form, the signature will be saved and it will be previewed by attaching the source file to an `<img>` element.

What I would like to do is I have a `<button>` that will show a modal that contains a signature pad and once the modal is closed, the signature will be transferred to another `<div>` wherein its size will shrink depending on the div's size without having to save the signature on a file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). This will give you an image of the canvas as a [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), which you can then add to your page as an image.

Here's a simple example:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw something
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 160, 60);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.font = "50px monospace";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("image", 100, 50);

// Make the image and put it in the output
let uri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),
    outdiv = document.querySelector('#out'),
    outimg = new Image();
outimg.src = uri;
outdiv.appendChild(outimg);
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <h6>Canvas with border</h6>
  <canvas width="200" height="100"
          style="border: 1px solid black;">
  </canvas>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <h6>Output image in a <code>div</code></h6>
  <div id="out"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I suddenly realized it after posting the question that there's a data url lol. Thanks